# Woocommerce: Link Subscription Product to Bundled Product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, subscriptions

I'm trying to find a solution that can link a Woocommerce Subscription to a Bundled Product.

What I want to do is offer a Subscription that a buyer can sign up to and then on a monthly basis they get sent a collection of predefined items that I sell elsewhere on the site.

The setup I want is a bit like https://www.lootcrate.com/ but I also want to be able to sell the individually items separately on the store and maintain inventory management.

Current installed plugins include: 
http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/
http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/

Comment: I know this is being worked on and is in a very alpha state. I couldn't say when it might be ready for testing, but probably pay attention to the Prospress blog.

Comment: Did you ever get this work together? I still can't seem to find the best solution on this.